# Submit poster in A4 size

Tags: paper-size, posters

I have created a conference poster in Latex and in the template that I am using there are the following specifications:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Parameters
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{297mm}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{594mm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{420mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-.5in}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{624mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{410mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2explus2ex}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.01\textwidth}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.001\textwidth}
\newlength{\boxwidth}
\setlength{\boxwidth}{0.975\textwidth}
\setlength{\boxwidth}{0.915\textwidth}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0cm}
```

Now I have to submit the PDF for a flash presentation and there is written that the submitted document should be in A4 size. What should I change?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Open your viewer, hit print, search for a PDF printer, choose borderless and save.

Comment: You could use instead `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`. So paper dimensions are A4 (210 mm x 297 mm) or `\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{297mm}` and `\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{210mm}`

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thank you for your help. But when I open the PDF to print it, I see that it does not fit. Is it normal?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Sorry, it seems to be working. I open it with Preview (Mac) and it seems to be fine. By changing these two parameters I should be fine for the A4 size, right?

Comment: Sorry `\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}` and `\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}` will work. I dont know the parameter pdfpageheight. Its easier with `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` or with `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` instead of using setlength. Hint: Your MWE isen't complete, it isen't compilable... . The pdf size you can check with your pdf viewer...

Comment: @Bobyandbob If I change paperwidth and paperheight, I get the problem I was desiring before. I see only a small portion of the poster. Even if I use a4paper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59819/discussion-between-bobyandbob-and-sensitive-scientist).